# How to match a key using regex in json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, text-processing

I have a json structure. i want to match a key if that key matches with regex it should skip that key and move to next key and need to print content of that key

This is my json structure

if regex matches with key which starts with 1. (a) this kind of condition it has to do nothing and move to 2 key

if a key starts with this condition it need to skip that key

```
1. (a)
```

```
data={
  "Name": "Sender",
  "subject": {
    "0": "subject",
    "1": {
      "1. (a) This subject ": {
        "(a) includes": [],
        "(b) srind": [],
        "(c) culture": []
      }
      },
      "2": {
      "2. This subject ": {
        "(a) includes": [],
        "(b) srind": [],
        "(c) culture": []

      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
import re

regex=r"[0-9]+\.\(.*\).*"
match=re.match(regex,s.keys())

if match:
    continue
```

It has to print only these

```
       "(a) includes": [],
        "(b) srind": [],
        "(c) culture": []
```

Comment: describing the condition with some example  will help too, also how deep can your dictionary go?

Comment: It looks like similar structure. it will not go more deeper@DeveshKumarSingh

Comment: okay can you describe your regex more concretely with examples

Comment: Not sure your question has any relation to json. It looks like you already has python dict which you want traverse. It's not clear does your desired result print from 1. or from 2. and why.

Comment: It's just not for printing there is further process i need to make with those things .

Just i want to match key of dictionary if key matches has to skip that key

Comment: "[a-z]+\.\(.*\).*" doesn't match nor "1. (a) This subject ", neither "(a) includes"

Comment: i  made a mistake here now i corrected it. @Sav

Answer (score 0):

As far as can get your question is about traversing python dict keys. Here is the recursive generator:

```
# traverse dictionary generates all of keys including subdicts
def get_keys(dct):
  for key, val in dct.items():
    if isinstance(val, dict):  # Depth first
      yield from get_keys(val)
    yield key

# filter keys
result = [k for k in get_keys(data) if not re.match(r"[0-9]+\.\(.*\).*", k)]
```

for you data result will:

```
['Name',
 '0',
 '(a) includes',
 '(b) srind',
 '(c) culture',
 '1',
 '(a) includes',
 '(b) srind',
 '(c) culture',
 '2',
 'subject']
```

it is all of keys in dict not matching pattern.